# next-auth ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:80

Tags: docker, docker-compose, keycloak

I am using Next-auth with keycloak and docker-compose and I get this error:

```
[next-auth][error][GET_AUTHORIZATION_URL_ERROR]
arcade-iori         | https://next-auth.js.org/errors#get_authorization_url_error connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:80 {
arcade-iori         |   message: 'connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:80',
arcade-iori         |   stack: 'Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:80\n' +
arcade-iori         |     '    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1161:16)',
arcade-iori         |   name: 'Error'
arcade-iori         | }
arcade-iori         | [next-auth][error][SIGNIN_OAUTH_ERROR]
arcade-iori         | https://next-auth.js.org/errors#signin_oauth_error connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:80 {
arcade-iori         |   error: {
arcade-iori         |     message: 'connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:80',
arcade-iori         |     stack: 'Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:80\n' +
arcade-iori         |       '    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1161:16)',
arcade-iori         |     name: 'Error'
arcade-iori         |   },
arcade-iori         |   provider: {
arcade-iori         |     id: 'keycloak',
arcade-proxy        | 172.30.0.1 - - [02/Feb/2022:04:52:58 +0000] "POST /api/auth/signin/keycloak HTTP/1.1" 302 5 "http://localhost/api/auth/signin?callbackUrl=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2F" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/97.0.4692.99 Safari/537.36" "-"
arcade-iori         |     name: 'Keycloak',
arcade-iori         |     wellKnown: 'http://localhost/auth/realms/myrealm/.well-known/openid-configuration',
arcade-iori         |     type: 'oauth',
arcade-iori         |     authorization: { params: [Object] },
arcade-iori         |     checks: [ 'pkce', 'state' ],
arcade-iori         |     idToken: true,
arcade-iori         |     profile: [Function: profile],
arcade-iori         |     clientId: 'myclientnext',
arcade-iori         |     clientSecret: 'a2D7ZgIFMeijlfbKOi6vZ30dhNUZhrT3',
arcade-iori         |     issuer: 'http://localhost/auth/realms/myrealm',
arcade-iori         |     signinUrl: 'http://localhost/api/auth/signin/keycloak',
arcade-iori         |     callbackUrl: 'http://localhost/api/auth/callback/keycloak'
arcade-iori         |   },
arcade-iori         |   message: 'connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:80'
arcade-iori         | }
```

This is the Next-auth config:

import NextAuth from "next-auth"
import KeycloakProvider from "next-auth/providers/keycloak";

```
export default NextAuth({
  secret: process.env.SECRET,
  site: process.env.NEXTAUTH_URL,
  providers: [
    KeycloakProvider({
      clientId: 'myclientnext',
      clientSecret: 'a2D7ZgIFMeijlfbKOi6vZ30dhNUZhrT3',
      issuer: 'http://localhost/auth/realms/myrealm',
    })
  ],
})
```

This is my docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3.7'

volumes:
  keycloak_db_data:
      driver: local

networks:
  arcadenet:
    driver: bridge

services:

  keycloak-db:
    image: postgres:11.2
    container_name: arcade-keycloak-db
    volumes:
      - keycloak_db_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: arcadecloack
      POSTGRES_USER: arcade
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: arcade
    networks:
      - arcadenet

  keycloak:
    image: quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:16.1.0
    container_name: arcade-keycloak
    environment:
      DB_VENDOR: POSTGRES
      DB_ADDR: arcade-keycloak-db
      DB_DATABASE: arcadecloack
      DB_USER: arcade
      DB_SCHEMA: public
      DB_PASSWORD: arcade
      KEYCLOAK_USER: admin
      KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD: admin
      PROXY_ADDRESS_FORWARDING: true
      # Uncomment the line below if you want to specify JDBC parameters. The parameter below is just an example, and it shouldn't be used in production without knowledge. It is highly recommended that you read the PostgreSQL JDBC driver documentation in order to use it.
      #JDBC_PARAMS: "ssl=true"
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    depends_on:
      - keycloak-db
    networks:
      - arcadenet

  iori:
    stdin_open: true # docker run -i
    tty: true        # docker run -t
    build:
        context: ../iori/
        dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: iori
    container_name: arcade-iori
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    volumes:
      - '../iori/:/app'
      - '/app/node_modules'
    networks:
      - arcadenet

  proxy:
    image: nginx
    container_name: arcade-proxy
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - 80:80
    volumes:
      - ./default-proxy.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:ro
    networks:
      - arcadenet
```

This is the default-proxy.conf:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    listen  [::]:80;
    server_name  localhost;

    location /keycloak/ {
        proxy_pass          http://arcade-keycloak:8080/;
        proxy_set_header    Host               $host;
        proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP          $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For    $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Host   $host;
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Server $host;
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Port   $server_port;
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Proto  $scheme;
    }


    location /auth/ {
        proxy_pass          http://arcade-keycloak:8080/auth/;
        proxy_set_header    Host               $host;
        proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP          $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For    $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Host   $host;
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Server $host;
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Port   $server_port;
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Proto  $scheme;
    }

    location / {

        proxy_pass http://arcade-iori:3000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;

    }

    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }
}
```